# NPM - How to use local component file as package

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have big project build with `React` and `react-router-dom` and few days ago I started to use `NextJS` and I see that NextJS doesn't have some features that `react-router-dom` have so I wrote a component file that will do the missing features combine it with NextJS

Here is the file

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import Link from 'next/link'

const NavLink = ({ children, activeClassName, ...props }) => {
    const { asPath } = useRouter()
    const childClassName = props.className || ''

    // pages/index.js will be matched via props.href
    // pages/about.js will be matched via props.href
    // pages/[slug].js will be matched via props.as
    const { to, ...rest } = props;
    const className = asPath === props.to ? `${childClassName} ${activeClassName}`.trim() : childClassName

    return (
        <Link {...rest} href={to} passHref={true} className={className}><a>
            {children}
        </a></Link>
    )
}

export default NavLink
```

I'm wondering, how can I use this file as a package so I can avoid importing it locally.

I have a lot of nested components and its really wasting of time to do that

Like is there a way to use this file like this

`import NavLink fron 'my-navlink';`

Instead of

`import NavLink fron '../.../components/public/ns/navlink.js';`

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Module path aliases](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases) :

just create a tsconfig.json or jsconfig.json file :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@my-navlink": ["components/public/ns/navlink.js"]
    }
  }
}
```

And then anywhere in your pages/components you can import it :

```
import NavLink fron '@my-navlink';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nico! You saved my time!!!! Thanks